# When a semigroup can be embedded into a group

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

Under what assumptions can a semigroup $(S,*)$ be embedded into a group?

Comment: I somehow misunderstood the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77266/how-to-get-a-group-from-a-semigroup/ - I haven't read it carefully enough back than. I started to write an answer, which was of no use for that question. AFAIK asking and answer own question is ok here - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ And I am sure other people will be able to add more interesting information to this.

Comment: A related (stronger!) question is the following: Let $\langle X; \mathbf{r}\rangle$ be a presentation such that every relator is a positive word, or is (up to cyclic shift) of the form $uv^{-1}$ where $u$ and $v$ are positive words (by "positive word" I mean the word). Such a presentation clearly defines a monoid. Then does the monoid given by the presentation embed in the group given by the presentation? Coxeter groups, for example, have a positive solution to this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is clear that if a semigroup is embedded into a group, it must be [cancellative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup).

Clifford, Preston: The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups - [Page 34](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vXG2rjCUmUC&pg=PA34). See also A. Nagy: Special classes of semigroups, Theorem 3.10,
[p.46](http://books.google.com/books?id=BmyCMoEU1n4C&pg=PA46)

> A commutative semigroup can be embedded in a group if and only if it is cancellative. The usual procedure for doing this by means of ordered pairs, is just like that of embedding an integral domain in a field.

This construction is sometimes called [group of
quotients](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22group+of+quotients%22&btnG=). This [article at proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Structure_on_Commutative_Semigroup_by_its_Cancellable_Elements) is somewhat related to this construction.

For non-commutative semigroups, the situation is more complicated.

Clifford, Preston: The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups - [Page
36](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vXG2rjCUmUC&pg=PA36)

> A cancellative semigroup $S$ can be embedded in a group of left quotients of $S$ if
>   and only if it is right reversible.

This paper might also be of interest: George C. Bush: [The embeddability of a semigroup--Conditions common to Mal'cev and Lambek](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1971-0281814-4), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 157 (1971), 437-448.

EDIT: See also this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups) which contains all the information I've given above and also a few further references. (Perhaps I should have searched wikipedia first, before posting this...)

Comment: It is also called the group of *differences* when using additive notation.